# Communities Enabled Breaks Our Site in "Force.com Sites"

Tags: visualforce, community, force.com-sites

Does anyone know why a Working Sites (VF) Solution using Guest Access would break when Communities is Enabled?

Basically our home page is returning us a generic Error:

```
"Authorization Required

You must first log in or register before accessing this page.
If you have forgotten your password, click Forgot Password to reset it"
```

All relevant VF access has been given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would have been difficult for someone to answer, as there may be various reason why enabling communities would stop Sites from working.

**So Reason 1:**

Code which changes it's result based on Community Enabled or Not:

```
Network.forwardToAuthPage(startUrl, pageRef);
```

This method does not forward to Auth for Guest when Community is not enabled, but does forward to Auth when Community is Enabled. And hence the Site breaks due to Authorization now Required for Guest. Not sure why our site did not redirect to the Login Page (that's the point right???).
Guest Users is seemingly "Login: Not Allowed" (Makes no sense)
So anyway we removed the method for pages where Guest access is allowed.

ref:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_network.htm

Quote:

"**Usage**

If Communities isn’t enabled for the user’s organization or the user is currently in the internal organization, returns null."